# What can you suspect is the issue with a Windows computer that cannot access other computers

Tags: installation

What can you suspect is the issue with a Windows computer that cannot access other computers by using a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) but can by using an IP address?

Comment: Can we have more information, in particular what router you are using.